# Perl default variable $_

Tags: perl

I thought I understood map however the following has results that I don't understand. I know why it's happening I just don't know how it is happening.

The problem is that the contents of @array are changing because `$_` is being reset during `_do_stuff_to_file` call. so what is printed is `here: \nhere:\n` when I expect it to be `here: donkie\nhere: kong\n`.

**Note:** This is not tested code. It's just what I remember seeing from lab. Why are the contents of `@array` changing?

If I set `$_` to `$f` before returning 1 from `_some_func`. Then the array is still intact.

Here is an example program to illustrate what I am seeing:

```
my @array = ("donkie", "kong");
map { push @junk, _some_func('blah', $_); } @array;

if (join ('', @junk) !~ /0/)
{   # for example sake this is always true since return 1 from _some_func.
    print map { "here: $_\n"; } @array;
}

sub _some_func
{   # for example sake, lets say $f always exists as a file.
    my $j = shift;
    my $f = shift;
    return 0 if !open(FILE, "< $f");
    close FILE;
    _do_stuff_to_file($f);

    return 1;
}


sub _do_stuff_to_file
{
    my $f = shift;
    open(IN, "< $f");
    open(OUT, "> $f.new");

    while (<IN>)
    {
        print OUT;
    }

    close IN;
    close OUT;
}
```

Comment: Your question already contains its own answer -- you already explained how it's happening. Do you want to change your question to something like "how do I avoid letting stuff clobber `$_`? Because that's one we can answer (and Michael Carman mostly already has).

Comment: I approve hobbs suggested question title. @yesterday Could you change it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many functions in Perl use the default variable `$_`. Among these are `map` and the readline operator `<>`. Like `foreach`, `map` makes the loop variable an alias for each element of the list it processes. What's happening is that this line:

```
while (<IN>)
```

is assigning to `$_` while the aliasing of the `map` is in effect. This is one of the problems with using `$_` (or any other global variable) -- strange action at a distance. If you're going to use `$_`, localize it first:

```
local $_;
while (<IN>)
...
```

Alternately, use a lexical variable instead:

```
while (my $line = <IN>)
```

Comment: but why does using $_ change the contents of the array? isnt $_ just a variable that is a copy of the current value of the array?

Answer (score 4):

modifying $_ will change your initial array, because $_ is an alias to current element. Your code should look like this:

```
my @array = ("donkie", "kong");
my @junk=map {_some_func('blah', $_) } @array;

if (join ('', @junk) !~ /0/)
{   # for example sake this is always true since return 1 from _some_func.
    print map { "here: $_\n"; } @array;
}

sub _some_func
{   # for example sake, lets say $f always exists as a file.
    my $j = shift;
    my $f = shift;
    return 0 if !-e $f;
    _do_stuff_to_file($f);
    return 1;
}


sub _do_stuff_to_file
{
    my $f = shift;
    local $_;
    open(IN, "<",$f);
    open(OUT, ">", "$f.new");

    while (<IN>)
    {
        print OUT;
    }

    close IN;
    close OUT;
}
```

P.S. map returns array with same number of elements (if scalar is returned from block). grep returns only elements for which block is true.

Comment: The list `map` returns doesn't necessarily have the same number of elements as its input. e.g. `@doubled = map { $_, $_ } (1 .. 5)`

Answer (score 4):

Most things that set $_ implicitly alias it, so won't cause this problem; the exception is `while (<filehandle>)`.  While you can localize $_ (ideally with `my $_;`), it's better just to never let while implicitly set $_.  Do `while ( my $line = <filehandle> )` instead.  (The special implicit defined() still happens.)

Answer (score 0):

I approve the answers from Alexander and Michael: `_do_stuff_to_file()` is changing the value of `$_`.
As in the context of `map` `$_` is just a name for the storage of the mapped element, the array is changed.

Alexander and Michael propose to change `_do_stuff_to_file()` so they do not affect the `$_` value. This is good practice to local-ize special variables such as `$_` to avoid perturbing the outside scope.

Here is an alternative solution that avoid touching that function: "break" the link inside the map block by local-izing before calling the function:

```
map { my $x=$_; local $_; push @junk, _some_func('blah', $x); } @array;
```

or more following the common style:

```
@junk = map { my $x=$_; local $_; _some_func('blah', $x) } @array;
```

Comment: Or `my $_;` before the map will cause map to use a lexical $_, not the global.  (5.10+)

Comment: @ysth "my $_" will create a new variable lexical to the map block. But it will not affect the _some_func() and _do_stuff_to_file() contexts so this will not fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, it will fix the problem for *that* map, unless you *want* them to be able to change the aliased values in @array.